# NoobProgramer = "Need explanation on this JQUERY smoothscrolling code"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

What does the below Javascript do? Could someone explain what each line in this smooth scrolling API does?

```
    $('a').click(function(){        //when you click 'a' run this function
       $('html, body').animate({              // animate what is in the html and body?
         scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top //grab coordinates?
      }, 800);                               // scroll speed?
       return false;                        // not sure what this means 
     });
```

Comment: `return false;` cancels the click action. Documentation on animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Jquery multiple selectors https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Almost all good...`$('html, body')` are dom selectors(I think that html do not to be included)...and `return false` prevents the `a` to work as expected(you are implementing a custom behavior when you click on an `a` element, so you don't need the default behavior)

Comment: `return false` works the same as `function(ev) { ev.preventDefault();`, as @epascarello said, it just makes it so when you click the link it won't redirect to the `href=""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok let's start, the first 2 lines are correct from your investigation

```
$('a').click(function(){        //when you click 'a' run this function
   $('html, body').animate({     // animate the actual body and html element?
```

The next line is a bit tricky. Let's break it down

```
$(this).attr("href")
```

the clicked element's (a) href attribute value (in this case it could be something like #test1 or #test2

```
$($(this).attr("href")
```

if the above has the value '#test1' the selector becomes $('#test1') which mathces all elements with `id=test1`

```
$().offset().top
```

you get the offset method that has the coordinates of the element to the document. One of the variables is top which is the distance from the top of the document.

And so the next line will find the total amount of pixels that is needed to scroll

```
     scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
  }, 800);         // this is the scroll speed
   return false;    // this will stop the anchor element from executing the default functionality, which is actually navigating to the href specified.
 });
```

I hope this helps :P